# Не выводится li элемент в реакте, помогите понять ошибку

Tags: reactjs

Всем добрый день. Возникла проблема, при попытке добавить li в имеющийся ul возникает ошибка `TypeError: this.state.objInfo.map is not a function`

```
    class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            objInfo : [],
            mean : ''
        }
    }

    showMeanInConsole = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            const newObject = {id: + new Date(), mean: this.state.mean, check: false};
            this.setState ({
                objInfo : this.state.objInfo.push(newObject),
                mean : ''
            })
            console.log(this.state.objInfo, `!!!`);
    }
    }

    meaning = (e) => {
        this.setState ({
            mean : e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.meaning} onKeyDown={this.showMeanInConsole} value={this.state.mean} placeholder="What needs to be done?" className="input"></input>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.objInfo.map((el) => <li key={el.id}>{el.mean}</li>)}
                </ul>
                {/* <div className='newDiv'>{this.state.mean}</div> */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Todo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` возвращает не новый массив, а длину массива. Поэтому при добавлении у вас вместо массива `objInfo` становился равен целому числу. Ниже исправленный пример

```js
class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            objInfo : [],
            mean : ''
        }
    }

    showMeanInConsole = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            const newObject = {id: + new Date(), mean: this.state.mean, check: false};
            let objInfo = this.state.objInfo;
            objInfo.push(newObject);
            this.setState ({
                objInfo : objInfo,
                mean : ''
            })
            console.log(this.state.objInfo, `!!!`);
        }
    }

    meaning = (e) => {
        this.setState ({
            mean : e.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.meaning} onKeyDown={this.showMeanInConsole} value={this.state.mean} placeholder="What needs to be done?" className="input"></input>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.objInfo.map((el) => <li key={el.id}>{el.mean}</li>)}
                </ul>
                {/* <div className='newDiv'>{this.state.mean}</div> */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Todo/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов и каков best practics?